# Name this electronic connector

Tags: connector, identification

```
Pins = 16x2
Space between pins = around 2mm
```

What i really need is the name of a female adaptor to connect to it in order to have cables like [this](http://www.geeetech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/3.2TFT-uno.jpg). Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I don't know why everyone's insisting that it can't be a 2mm-pitch connector. In my recent experience, they're just as common as the 2.54-mm (0.100") variety. To verify: is the total length of the header 32mm or 1.6" (40.6mm)?

Comment: If the pin pitch is 2mm, then two 20-pin 2mm pitch JTAG connectors side by side (yes, that's one of the ARM JTAG header **standards**) ought to serve the purpose. For those who doubt: Here is just one standard JTAG probe which uses 20 pin 2 mm IDC: http://www.code-red-tech.com/red-probe.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIL / dual-in-line header.
These are available with insulation displacement connectors (IDC) allowing termination to ribbon cables, and can be bought preterminated.  Molex make these and also probably have solderable versions (you'll be sorry).

IF the pitch is 2.54mm, which seems likely, then an old floppy disk drive cable (34 pins) is probably an easy solution.

---

You MAY have a 2mm pitch header but 2.54 mm or 2.5mm is much more likely.

Spacing is usually either 2.54mm = 0.1" or 2.5mm = not quite 0.1".
The two are interchangeable (for non-purists) after a fashion for small numbers of pins but get out of alignment by 0.04mm per pin.

When measuring something like this it is a very very (very) good idea to give people as accurate a pitch measurement as you reasonably can. In this case you have 16 pins so there are 15 x pitch distances between 1st and last pin. Measure this distance and divide by 15. Or measure 10 pitches between pins 1 & 11 and divide by 10.

Even for 10 pins 10 x 2.5 = 25mm and 10 x 2.54 = 25.4mm so you could probably detect the difference with a standard metal metric ruler calibrated in mm. At 15 pitches it is 37.5 and 38.1 mm for a difference of 0.6mm. OR if it is some pitch closest to 2mm (unlikely) it will be different.

---

2 of these](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/973) from Polulu may do, depending on how they butt, BUT you can buy 32 pin ones.

An old floppy disk drive cable is 2 x 17 pin.

A HDD parallel access cable is 40 pin

[Various examples here](http://www.lulusoso.com/products/Idc-Flat-Ribbon-Cable-Connector.html)

Mouser have a very nice parametric selector that includes [cable assemblies](http://nz.mouser.com/Wire-Cable/Cable-Assemblies/_/N-5gh1/) BUT no 32 way flat cables listed. (Check for yourself just in case).

Answer (score 2):

It is just a 16 x 2 pin header.

A 34 way IDC cable will fit just fine (you might even be able to find one inside an old computer).

This is what a 16 way looks like. You might have to buy the connector and the cable separately. (pic from wikipedia)

[image: pic]

Answer (score -1):

32 way box header, 0.1" pitch

perhaps?

Comment: 0.26" ~ 6.6 mm. Sounds more like a regular 0.1" pitch header? If "around 2 mm" could actually be 2.54 mm.